# Add missing rows within groups

Tags: python, pandas

Suppose dataframe:

```
df = pd.DataFrame({
    "id":     [1, 1, 1, 2, 2, 3],
    "day":    [1, 2, 3, 1, 3, 2],
    "value":  [1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6],
})
```

I need all ids to have the same set of days. How to add rows with missing days?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

For solutions with multiple columns filled by `0` for new missing rows use [`DataFrame.unstack`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.unstack.html) with [`DataFrame.stack`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.stack.html) working with `MultiIndex` by [`DataFrame.set_index`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.set_index.html), last convert again to columns by [`DataFrame.reset_index`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.reset_index.html):

```
df = df.set_index(['id','day']).unstack(fill_value=0).stack().reset_index()
print (df)
   id  day  value
0   1    1      1
1   1    2      2
2   1    3      3
3   2    1      4
4   2    2      0
5   2    3      5
6   3    1      0
7   3    2      6
8   3    3      0
```

Another solution with [`DataFrame.reindex`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.reindex.html) by [`MultiIndex.from_product`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.MultiIndex.from_product.html),  working with `MultiIndex` by [`DataFrame.set_index`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.set_index.html), last convert again to columns by [`DataFrame.reset_index`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.reset_index.html):

```
df = df.set_index(['id','day'])
m = pd.MultiIndex.from_product(df.index.levels, names=df.index.names)

df = df.reindex(m, fill_value=0).reset_index()
print (df)
   id  day  value
0   1    1      1
1   1    2      2
2   1    3      3
3   2    1      4
4   2    2      0
5   2    3      5
6   3    1      0
7   3    2      6
8   3    3      0
```

Answer (score 4):

IIUC

```
df=df.pivot(*df.columns).fillna(0).stack().reset_index()
   id  day    0
0   1    1  1.0
1   1    2  2.0
2   1    3  3.0
3   2    1  4.0
4   2    2  0.0
5   2    3  5.0
6   3    1  0.0
7   3    2  6.0
8   3    3  0.0
```

Comment: Thx for you elegant solution. jezrael's variant works with multiple value columns, thus I prefer his solution